# Unable to install PHP zip archive with PHP 7.2

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-ziparchive

I am running into some issues installing the PHP zip archive and not sure how to fix this. I am running Ubuntu 18 with PHP 7.2

The error I receive in terminal is

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 php7.2-zip : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 7.2.5- 
1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: `apt-get install php7.2-common php7.2-zip`

Comment: php7.2-common is already the newest version (7.2.5-1+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+1).

Answer (score 2):

I tried changing the repository list with:

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted universe

But none of them seem to work, but I finally found a repository that works running the following command

**add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php**

And then updating and installing normally the package using apt-get

[php7.2-zip Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXkK1.png)

As you can see its installed at last.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04, this can happen if your missing the "security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe" repo.

Add it to your /etc/apt/sources.list, update and then it will install normally.

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe" >>  
/etc/apt/sources.list
apt update
apt install php7.2-zip
```

Answer (score 0):

adding line `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe` in /etc/apt/sources.list works like a charm